# "PDO method not found" inside PHP Function (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, phpstorm

I wrote a function in php that counts the amount of rows in a MySQL database, called count_series(). This function works fine, however,  PhpStorm gives me a 'method not found' error for the following the following functions: prepare(), execute(), rowCount().

Does anyone know what the cause of this may be?

```
/**
 * Connects to the database
 * @param $host
 * @param $db
 * @param $user
 * @param $pass
 * @return PDO
 */
function connect_db($host, $db, $user, $pass) {
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    ];
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo sprintf("Failed to connect. %s",$e->getMessage());
    }
    return $pdo;
}


/**
 * Returns the amount of series in the database
 * @param $db
 * @return mixed
 */
function count_series($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ddwt18_week1.series');
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code using `count_series`? Looks like the `$db` is not a `PDOStatement` object.

Comment: $db = connect_db('localhost', 'ddwt18_week1', 'ddwt18','ddwt18'); and
$serie_amount = count_series($db);

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($db);` inside `count_series`?

Comment: Use proper type hints -- either native PHP ones (where possible) or PHPDoc. It easily solves such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're omitting type hinting everywhere so PhpStorm (or even a human being) has no way to figure out by itself. Instead of this:

```
function count_series($db) {
}
```

... I'd expect to see something like:

```
function count_series(PDO $db): int {
}
```

... or at least this (if you need to support earlier PHP versions)

```
function count_series(PDO $db) {
}
```

Please replace `PDO` with the actual class name if it isn't that one.

Same for dobclocks (though they're actually redundant when it comes to code instellisense if the code is self-documenting). Instead of this:

```
 * @param $db
 * @return mixed
```

... use this:

```
 * @param PDO $db
 * @return int
```

Answer (score 0):

add inside try `return $pdo`under `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);`
And Also inside function `count_series()` add `$db=connect_db();`

Comment: I see now where the problem you  return $count; this return sql row count not select count ` $row =$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ` and return $row